# plotting multiple lines on same axis, but with different starting points

Tags: r, axis, lines

In my simplified example, I'm trying to plot the below lines `x` and `y`, but I want `y` to start at time 3 and go to 5. As of now `y` starts at time 1 and only goes to time 3.

```
x <- c(1, 3, 4, 7, 8)
y <- c(4, 2, 1)
plot.ts(x)
lines(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
plot(x=1:5, y=x, type="l")
points(x=3:5, y=y, type="l")
```

You have to set both *x* and *y* coordinates for a 2d plot. Otherwise R assumes they start at 1 and go to length(vector).

Answer (score 1):

What you really have is

```
y <- c(NA,4,2,1,NA)
```

[A good reference on missing values.](http://www.statmethods.net/input/missingdata.html)

If you have a large proportion of missing values in `y`, it may be more appropriate to store `y` in a data.frame

```
y.df <- data.frame(t=c(3,4,7), t=c(4,2,1))
lines(y~t, y.df)
```

Depending on the specifics, it may be advantageous to also store x in the same data frame.

Comment: But what if my x is really 200 observations and y is only over the final 25? I don't really want to add all those NA's